# Get The Full Height Of HTML Element That's Partially Hidden By Overflow:Hidden With JQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title says, how can I get the full height of an element that is partially hidden by it's container div using over: hidden. Almost as if it wasn't somewhat hidden and scrollable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use inner wrapper div and measure the height of that.

Comment: It only seems to return the height visible when i do that.

Comment: jQuery version of William's answer:  http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/gQanb/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">Short ribs frankfurter jerky, corned beef tongue chuck meatball. Hamburger drumstick chuck pork chop brisket, prosciutto leberkäse bresaola shank. Corned beef chuck prosciutto beef cow. Tail bresaola biltong, turkey beef beef ribs cow salami. Ground round sausage filet mignon andouille beef ribs, venison pork loin swine frankfurter turkey. Ball tip drumstick swine, ribeye t-bone chuck meatball brisket salami. Meatball pork chop corned beef filet mignon pastrami pork loin ham t-bone andouille kielbasa.

    Drumstick spare ribs shank, pastrami bacon biltong swine meatball capicola. Chicken salami short ribs meatloaf cow kielbasa. Chuck ham hock venison rump, flank frankfurter short ribs sirloin ribeye ham leberkäse capicola drumstick. Capicola ball tip beef tail pastrami, shank pork loin pancetta frankfurter swine ribeye andouille. Andouille chicken pork belly leberkäse pastrami, swine corned beef. Jerky rump frankfurter, short loin hamburger beef kielbasa biltong ground round fatback. Pork chop tri-tip ham hock ham.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#content {
    height: auto;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

jQuery/JS

```
$('#content').height()
```

DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/gQanb/4/

Comment: Thank you for answering, but my content does not have a set height. Any way to auto set it, or get it?

Comment: See updated answer... no set height and returns "270" for me.

Comment: Okay, this worked. I had the inset element set to height: 100%. Thanks! I'll give credit to the other guy because he was first, but I definitely plused this answer up! Thanks again!

Comment: Mine is the jQuery solution, and this is not the better answer?  I also took the time to update as per your new requirement and post the code in the open.

Comment: How is yours the better solution? He asked for a JavaScript or jQuery solution. And, jQuery IS JavaScript. All you did was copy my code and change one line to use jQuery. We both updated our answers to support his new requirement.

Comment: @Wiliam: When somebody tags a question with jQuery, I give them a JS solution that utilizes the jQuery library.  From the start, my answer is `.height()`, based solely on comments under the OP and I posted the full code within my post rather than simply linking to a jsFiddle.  When jsFiddle links go bad, my solution will still be good for anyone.  SO is about quality postings, not a race to the finish line.

Comment: @Sparky672 I didn't say it was a race. But, you should not ask him to accept your answer. It is his choice who's answer is best, and he can make the choice to change that if he wants.

Comment: @William: I never asked him to do anything, and he chose to change his mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `clientHeight` property. http://jsfiddle.net/gQanb/

Comment: OP asked for jQuery solution... presumably, he's already using it.

Comment: This would work, but the contained element does not have a set height and cannot, so it only returns the part visible in the window.

Comment: Okay, this worked. I had the inset element set to height: 100%. Thanks!