# How to get the full height of an UL with overflow set?

Tags: jquery

I have a UL with an `overflow-y:scroll;` set so it scrolls. How to I get the full height of the list as `$(ul).height()` just gives the height of the scroll viewport not the height of the full list.

**html**

```
<ul style="overflow-y:scroll; height: 50px;">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Things like [Get The Full Height Of HTML Element That's Partially Hidden By Overflow:Hidden With JQuery / Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830489/get-the-full-height-of-html-element-thats-partially-hidden-by-overflowhidden-w) wont work as there is no inner wrapper, there is just the list.

I'm trying to get the list to scroll to the bottom when I append a new item, but...

`$("ul").attr({ scrollTop: NeedHeightHere });`

Comment: as far as I can tell the answers provided produce exactly the same answer: http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/VJwsz/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the **[`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight)** DOM property, supported by all modern browsers (even by IE):

```
var wholeHeight = $("ul")[0].scrollHeight;
```

Alternatively, you can select the first and last item in the list, get the top offset, and substract these from each other. Add the height of the final list element, and the result is equivalent to the scrollHeight (after adding top and bottom paddings of UL).

```
var ul = $("ul"),
    last = ul.children().last();
var wholeHeight = last.offset().top - ul.children().first().offset().top
                  + last.outerHeight()
                  + parseFloat(ul.css("padding-top"))
                  + parseFloat(ul.css("padding-bottom"));
```

Note: The first method is much more efficient. The second method might fail to produce the right result when the last element is absolutely positioned, or floating.

Comment: You can use `scrollTop()` to set the position `$('ul').scrollTop($('ul')[0].scrollHeight);`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try iterating through the LI's and adding their height together:

```
var totalHeight=0;
$("ul li").each(function() {
   totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight(true); // to include margins
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#your_div')[0].scrollHeight
```